# I don't have "Database Development Perspective" in Eclipse Java SE IDE

Tags: java, database, eclipse

I want to connect a mysql database with eclipse, i have the "java developers" edition of eclipse indigo 3.7.1 and in a lot of tutorials says "open the database development perspective " for connect, but.......

I don't have that perspective, in eclipse for java ee developers has that perspective but in my java se ( standard ) no :(

How i can get it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The Java EE Eclipse edition comes with some plugins preinstalled.

Install the Database Tools Platform (DTP) Plugin. Here is a [tutorial](http://www.vogella.de/articles/EclipseDataToolsPlatform/article.html).

Comment: @Arjan Tijms i am also having the same problem.can you give suggestion

Answer (score 16):

Another way and for other versions of eclipse such as neon, Click help link on the eclipse app, then click install new sofware

[image]

Then you can be able to install the database development perspective from there

[image]

Answer (score 7):

If Database Development Perspective is not listed in your Open Perspective dialog, then you must have to download using Help > Install New Software > Open Work With Combobox Option and choose `Oxygen - http://download.eclipse.org/releases/oxygen` or the version like Juno, Kepler, Luna, Mars, Neon, Oxygen, Photan your eclipse version belongs to.

[image: Install_New_Software_Plugin]

Just after your selection, eclipse will list the softwares plugins required by you available to the above said url.

Simply check the Database Development > Next > Accept the Terms and Conditions > 
Finish and after installation restart your eclipse ide.

After restart go and choose your perspective.