# Where does Eclipse store my Derby Database files which I create with Java?

Tags: java, eclipse, derby

I've been searching for a little while and can't find where Eclipse Neon stores my database files which I create with Derby and Java.  Older documentation shows an "Apache Derby" option in the context menu, but that doesn't appear for me.

In the older documentation, I also saw something about an IJ SQL interface for Derby.  I would also like to know if this IJ interface is still available with Eclipse Neon, and how to open it.

Thanks!

Comment: Well, how is your program connecting to Derby?

Comment: I figured out that I hadn't created the database correctly before.  Once I issued a create=true statement, the database appeared in my project folder.  However, I am still interested to know if the IJ interface still exists, and if I can interface with the database through Eclipse apart from writing Java programs

Comment: Try switching to the "Database Development" Perspective in Eclipse.

Comment: Unfortunately "Database Development" doesn't appear in the "Open Perspective" window

Comment: See [I don't have “Database Development Perspective” in Eclipse Java SE IDE](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7923041/5221149).

Comment: Great!  Thank you!!

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that eclipse can store the Database, but you can write your Java code in eclipse that creates a Derby database, tables and so on, as well as you can use with the ij-tool of Derby database for create a database.

Two ways how to create a Derby database and where the database that created saved.

** By default, automatically database saved where you run the startNetworkServer.bat.

Sample example for creating a database from java code (eclipse):

```
public class CreateDatabase {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String driverName = "org.apache.derby.jdbc.ClientDriver";

        // Creating all tables for database DDL for TABLES
        try {
        Class.forName(driverName);

        System.out.println("driver loaded");

        String url = "jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/MyDB;create=true";

        // ARM technology
        try (Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(url);) {

            // get a connection to a specific database (inside ARM)
            System.out.println("connected to: " + con);
            Statement stmt = con.createStatement();

            // create a Statement for all tables

            String companyTable = "CREATE TABLE Company"
                    + "("
                    + "COMPANY_ID BIGINT NOT NULL GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY (START WITH 1, INCREMENT BY 1),"
                    + "COMPANY_NAME VARCHAR(20),"
                    + "COMPANY_PASSWORD VARCHAR(16),"
                    + "EMAIL VARCHAR(30),"
                    + "CONSTRAINT PRIME_COMPANY_ID PRIMARY KEY (COMPANY_ID)"
                    + ")";

            stmt.executeUpdate(companyTable);
            System.out.println("success: " + companyTable);

            String customerTable = "CREATE TABLE Customer"
                    + "("
                    + "CUSTOMER_ID BIGINT NOT NULL GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY (START WITH 1, INCREMENT BY 1),"
                    + "CUSTOMER_NAME VARCHAR(25),"
                    + "CUSTOMER_PASSWORD VARCHAR(16),"
                    + "CONSTRAINT PRIME_CUSTOMER_ID PRIMARY KEY (CUSTOMER_ID)"
                    + ")";
            stmt.executeUpdate(customerTable);
            System.out.println("success: " + customerTable);


            System.out.println("The database MyDB created successfully");

            }

            System.out.println("connection closed");

        } catch (ClassNotFoundException | SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}
```

---

Sample example for creating a database from ij-tool of (Derby):
go to bin directory of Derby database and - 
1. run the startNetworkServer.bat 
2. run the ij.bat
3. in ij-tool write `connect 'jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/MyDB;create=true';`

in 3rd steps we create a database that named MyDB and it appears in this - bin directory.

After the database created you can create the tables...
https://db.apache.org/derby/docs/10.7/ref/rrefsqlj24513.html#rrefsqlj24513